# How could I get data from related tables in DB using laravel eloquent paginate()?

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I have two tables posts and tags with models and pivot table `post_tag` for them.
I want to use eloquent paginate to get posts and send them via `response()->json()` (because it's an api endpoint) and it's working, but I can't get tags for those posts.

Code for api route

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($orderby, $order)
                ->paginate($pages, [
                    'title', 'slug', 'author',
                    'views', 'rating', 'vote_counter',
                    'body_length', 'description'
                ]);
return response()->json($posts);
```

But it doesn't send the related tags for this post. How could I do that?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below query.

```
$posts = Post::with('tags')->orderBy($orderby, $order)
                    ->paginate($pages, [
                        'title', 'slug', 'author',
                        'views', 'rating', 'vote_counter',
                        'body_length', 'description'
                    ]);
    return response()->json($posts);
```

Hope above query is helpful for you.